# Working with Notepad, XML, and Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In my work place we deal with a file type called .ENV which has inside it XML data from appraisal files. If you open the .env file with notepad there is a couple of lines of text before the opening tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and there is a bunch of code after the closing tag `</VALUATION_RESPONSE" encoding="utf-8"?>`. I would like to have my user select the `.env` file from `Application.GetOpenFilename` and then import in the portion of the file that is xml data.

If I manually open the .env file in notepad and delete everything before and after the `xml` tags and then save as `.xml` it imports into excel fine. So is there a way to have VBA open a file with notepad, delete everything before and after the xml tags, save the file as .xml and then import it?

I would upload a sample .env file but unfortunately they are filled with information that cannot be shared and I have no way to produce a dummy file.

I have worked out a solution. I don't really like it since it uses sendkeys but I could not figure out a different way to do it.

```
Sub test()
Dim Ret1
Dim Filename As String
Dim Ret2



Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Env Files (*.env*), *.env*", _
    , "Please select the Invoice Report file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

    Filename = "C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & Ret1

'   Debug.Print Ret1
RetVal = Shell(Filename, vbNormalFocus)

 'Send keys of actions to notepad
    SendKeys "^f", True
    SendKeys "<?xml version=", True
    SendKeys "~", True
    SendKeys "%{F4}", True
    SendKeys "+{Home}", True
    SendKeys "^+{Home}", True
    SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}", True
    SendKeys "^f", True
    SendKeys "</VALUATION_RESPONSE>", True
    SendKeys "~", True
    SendKeys "%{F4}", True
    SendKeys "+{End}", True
    SendKeys "^+{End}", True
    SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}", True
    SendKeys "</VALUATION_RESPONSE>", True
    SendKeys "%fa", True
    SendKeys "Converted.xml", True
    SendKeys "~", True
    SendKeys "%{F4}", True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be great if you could highlight the sourcecode with backticks: ``.

Comment: Man, that was one big, ugly codeblock. Kindly strip it all of formatting before you paste it. I tried my best with the above but it might have some errors I wasn't able to catch.

Comment: Sorry about the mess. Did not look that way in the preview. I think I have it cleaned up now.

Comment: By any chance, can you describe these extraneous lines? Are they just simple text or HTML as well?

Comment: They are text. The first line of one file is "DC%%STAM4   GUID/C9D76E4C-2E17-40C1-909A-EA5CAE506745"  Looks like info about the file that is meant for another program to read.

Comment: It's a GUID. Most probably just for tracking purposes. Hm. I think I have a solution. Will test it first. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String
Dim NewContent() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim NewLength As Long

NameOfFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Env Files (*.env*), *.env*", _
, "Please select the Invoice Report file")
If NameOfFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open NameOfFile For Input As #FileNum
i = 0

Do Until EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
    If InStr(DataLine, "<") <> 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve NewContent(1 To i)
        NewContent(i) = DataLine
    End If
Loop
Close #FileNum
NewLength = i

Open NameOfFile For Output As #FileNum
For i = 1 To NewLength
    Print #FileNum, NewContent(i)
Next i
Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

Logic was borrowed [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/705837-delete-rows-text-file-via-visual-basic-applications.html).

Pretty basic: Check if "<" is in line. If yes, then it ***probably*** is a valid line. Write to array if valid, otherwise ditch it.

We then rewrite the file completely with the stored values in the array. This basically shows the illusion that the lines without tags were deleted. You can change this to write to a new file instead, to preserve the old one.

**Tried and tested. Use this on a COPY of your invoice file.** Let us know if this helps.

### **EDIT:**

Another approach is to use boundaries and get the text inside. An example is as follows:

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String
Dim NewContent() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim NewLength As Long

NameOfFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Env Files (*.env*), *.env*", _
, "Please select the Invoice Report file")
If NameOfFile = "False" Then Exit Sub

FileNum = FreeFile()
Open NameOfFile For Input As #FileNum
i = 0
IsStart = False
IsEnd = False

Do Until IsEnd 'EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine

    If InStr(DataLine, "<?xml version=") <> 0 And InStr(DataLine, "</VALUATION_RESPONSE>") <> 0 Then
        IsStart = True
        IsEnd = True

    ElseIf InStr(DataLine, "<?xml version=") <> 0 Then
        IsStart = True

    ElseIf InStr(DataLine, "</VALUATION_RESPONSE>") <> 0 Then
        IsEnd = True

    End If

    If IsStart Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve NewContent(1 To i)
        NewContent(i) = DataLine
    End If

Loop

Close #FileNum
NewLength = i

Open NameOfFile For Output As #FileNum
For i = 1 To NewLength
    Print #FileNum, NewContent(i)
Next i
Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

This one checks the boundaries. If it's the standard opening XML tag, then it starts the storage of lines. If it hits the last tag you're targeting, it exits the loop after writing that one last line.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I just tested it out and it does what you said it would :) It is not a perfect solution because the lines that appear after the last xml tag do have < in them in places but it does cut the original file down significantly and gives me a place to work from. I wish there was a way to just pull everything between the opening and closing tags since I know what those tags will be every time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if you believed it was helpful and a viable solution. However, seeing as you did not get what you want, then feel free to leave it as is. Off the top of my head, it's actually pretty easy to do it another way. This was one of my fears as well: other lines having tags after the closing one. A simple reversal, though, as I said, will solve this neatly. :)

Comment: I think your second solution is just what I would be looking for but when I tried to test it I got an input past end of file error on the "Line Input #FileNum, DataLine" line

Comment: I think your second solution is just what I would be looking for but when I tried to test it I got an input past end of file error on the "Line Input #FileNum, DataLine" line

Comment: I figured out what was causing the error in the second option and have fixed it but in the end there is still unwanted text before and/or after the xml tags. If there is any text on the same dataline as the opening or closing xml tag then that text will stay.